# bash search for multiple patterns on different lines in a file

Tags: regex, bash, file, search, awk

I have a number of files and I want to filter out the ones that contain 2 patterns. However these patterns are on different lines. I've tried it using grep and awk but in both cases they only seem to work on matches patterns on the same line. I know grep is line based but I'm less familiar with awk. Here's what I came up with but it only works prints lines that match both strings:

```
awk '/string1/ && /string2/' file
```

Comment: Do you mean these patterns occur *across* lines? E.g. you want a file containing 'foo\nbar'?

Comment: @kojiro foo and bar are on separate lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grep will easily handle this using `xargs`:

```
grep -l string1 * | xargs grep -l string2
```

Use this command in the directory where the files are located, and resulting matches will be displayed.

Comment: Tried that but it seems to be treating the other words on that matched lines as files

Comment: Not sure I follow. The above command should show the filenames within a directory that contain the matching two strings — which is the expected behavior.

Comment: I'm searching in a git repo, and this worked: `git grep -l string2 | xargs grep -l string2` - note the lack of an asterisk before the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Depending om  whether you really want to search for regexps:

```
gawk -v RS='^$' '/regexp1/ && /regexp2/ {print FILENAME}' file
```

or for strings:

```
gawk -v RS='^$' 'index($0,"string1") && index($0,"string2") {print FILENAME}' file
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS to read the whole file as a single record.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with find

```
find -type f -exec bash -c "grep -q string1 {} && grep -q string2 {} && echo {}"  ";"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this with `GNU awk`:

```
awk '/foo/{seenFoo++} /bar/{seenBar++} seenFoo&&seenBar{print FILENAME;seenFoo=seenBar=0;nextfile}' file*
```

That says... if you see `foo`, increment variable `seenFoo`, likewise if you see `bar`, increment variable `seenBar`. If, at any point, you have seen both `foo` and `bar`, print the name of the current file and skip to the next input file ignoring all remaining lines in current file, and, before you start the next file, clear the flags to say we have seen neither `foo` nor `bar` in the new file.